# Using tensorflow classification for feature extraction

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, voxel

I am currently working on a system that extracts certain features out of 3D-objects (Voxelgrids to be precise), and i would like to compare those features to automatically made features when it comes to performance (classification) in a tensorflow cNN with some other data, but that is not the point here, just for background.
My idea now was, to take a dataset (modelnet10), train a  tensorflow cNN to classify them, and then use what it learned there on my dataset - not to classify, but to extract features.

So i want to throw away everything the cnn does,except for what it takes from the objects.

Is there anyway to get these features? and how do i do that? i certainly have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to train models exclusively for feature extraction. This is called transfer learning where you can either train your own model and then extract the features or you can extract features from pre-trained models and then use it in your task if your task is similar in nature to that of what the pre-trained model was trained for. You can of course find a lot of material online for these topics. However, I am providing some links below which give details on how you can go about it:

https://keras.io/api/applications/

https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-transfer-learning-when-developing-convolutional-neural-network-models/

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/27/keras-feature-extraction-on-large-datasets-with-deep-learning/

[https://www.kaggle.com/angqx95/feature-extractor-fine-tuning-with-keras](https://keras.io/api/applications/%20%20https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/%20%20https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-transfer-learning-when-developing-convolutional-neural-network-models/%20%20https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/27/keras-feature-extraction-on-large-datasets-with-deep-learning/%20%20https://www.kaggle.com/angqx95/feature-extractor-fine-tuning-with-keras)